# htaccess - Redirect when not

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rule to redirect all traffic to a subfolder.
However, now I need to stop it doing so in certain situations.

```
#
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mywebsite.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !cms/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/$1 [L]
#
```

If the incoming request is http://www.mywebsite.com/goodies/
I would like to ignore the above redirect.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your second condition line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !cms/
```

by

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cms|goodies)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add condition before RewriteRule as you do for cms/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !goodies/
```

Comment: thanks, didn't work for me - the only way I can get it working is if I take out the RewriteRule cms.